# Linux CPU Hog report

Tags: linux

I am wondering if there is a tool that will monitor all the process and send a daily report of which process where hogging resources per hour or something similar?

What I am after is when I see my cpu go up at certain times of the day, I want to know which processes where using the resources at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Historical statistics are integral to a well-run environment.  I would recommend taking a look at [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), and [sysstat](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/).

Comment: Yeah I am running all 3, but the extra info I am after is seeing when their is a CPU spike in cacti/monit/sysstat I am able to cross reference what processes where running at that time and their load.